# What is triggering the use of the word 'en' in this sentence?

Tags: traduction, anglais, en

- Il ne s'en intéressa pas moins à ce qu'il faisait au point de gagner

Fuller context. Here is the entire text:

> Pourtant la veille au soir, alors qu'il jouait à 'Concentration' avec
> ses filles, il avait beau savoir qu'il avait mis en route la mort, il
> ne s'en intéressa pas moins à ce qu'il faisait au point de gagner, à force
> d'attention.

It is from a French translation made in 1969 of an English-language novel, the original text being:

> Yet last night, playing Concentration with his two daughters, knowing he had set a death in motion, he cared enough to concentrate and win.

Comment: Please provide some context, especially the sentence preceding that one.

Comment: Hello. Can you provide more details about this sentence? Context, source and the like can be very helpful indeed.

Answer (score 3):

A justification of this turn is found in "LBU p. 869 § 676 a) 3°".

> **Fonctions de *en***
> *En* joue le rôle d'un syntagme introduit par *de*.
> **a)** complément de verbe
> **3°** Une cause non agissante revient à une idée d'opposition (comp.
> § 1032, 2°). Cela explique l'expression **n'en ... pas moins**, équivalent
> de *cependant*:
> ♦ Quelque faiblesse qu'elle eût mise dans sa tentative de départ, elle NE l'EN avait PAS
> MOINS *faite* (MUSSET, Conf, IV, 6).
> ♦ Nous fûmes d'accord pour protester que l'abbé gardait toute notre confiance. Mais le curé N'EN témoigna PAS MOINS, désormais, une grande froideur au séminariste (MAURIAC, Nœud de vip., VII).
> ♦ O'Brien à tête de mouton, O'Brien qui N'EN était PAS MOINS malicieux comme un singe (SIMENON, Maigret à New-York, II).
>
> Il est fâcheux de supprimer *en*, c'est-à-dire l'expression de la cause :
> ♦ Tu me rejettes dans mon vice. Je NE te remercie PAS MOINS [de la pipe offerte] (COPEAU,
> dans Copeau et Martin du G., Corresp., p. 592).
> ♦ Marguerite savait qu'Emile était
> au salon [...]. Elle n'y introduisit pas MOINS la visiteuse (SIMENON, Chat, V). [Est-ce
> la présence de y qui a empêché celle de en ?]
> ♦ L'objet de la pragmatique a beau être l'utilisation du langage dans le discours, elle NE s'occupe PAS MOINS, comme la sémantique, du sens (R.-M. DlLLER et Fr. RÉCANATI, dans Langue fr., mai 1979, p. 3).

As can be read in the second part this turn is used to refer to a *cause* (in the French "l'expression de la cause"), this cause being an agent of opposition. An equivalent would be as follows.

- Pourtant la veille au soir, alors qu'il jouait à 'Concentration' avec ses filles, il savait  qu'il avait mis en route la mort, **cependant** il s'intéressa  à ce qu'il faisait au point de gagner, à force d'attention.

The ineffective cause (French: cause non agissante) is, apparently, "il avait mis en route la mort"; it should impair the normal process, oppose it, but does not. It must be noticed that, in this equivalent formulation the negative form of the verb must be changed to the positive.

A certain number of cases of that usage is found [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ne%20s%27en%20int%C3%A9ressa%20pas%20moins%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr). A reading of those will help driving the idea home.

It must also be notice that there is redundancy somewhere or at least  a complication hidden in the context, as "pourtant" is equivalent to "cependant" ([réf.](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=synonyme+de+pourtant)).

Answer (score 0):

See the answer in a similar question posted here: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/sint%C3%A9resser-de-qqch.2578858/

> Le TLF [1] signale la construction vieillie s'intéresser de + infinitif,
> et il n'est pas impossible que certains locuteurs acceptent la même
> construction pour un complément nominal (s'intéresser de qqc), et à ce
> moment-là on aurait également s'en intéresser. Mais ce n'est pas le
> tour normal. Par contre, on dit se désintéresser de qqc / s'en
> désintéresser.
>
> Sinon, avec intéresser on peut avoir un en qui n'exprime pas le
> complément du verbe, par ex. dans Je ne m'en intéresse pas moins à tes
> problèmes.

According to Littré's (online) [dictionary](https://www.littre.org/definition/int%C3%A9resser)

> On a dit : s'intéresser d'une chose (emploi qui n'est aucunement
> fautif, et qui seulement est peu usité).

- Il faut laisser cette humeur
  aux esprits vulgaires qui s'intéressent de toutes les querelles des
  princes, Guez de Balzac, liv. II, lett. 1.
- Personne ne s'en intéresse,
  M. de Ste-Marthe, cité dans STE-BEUVE, Hist. de Port-Royal, t. III, p. 398.
- Il souffre tout ce que Dieu lui-même peut faire souffrir à un coupable qu'il est intéressé de punir, Massillon, Carême, Riche.

[1]: https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/int%C3%A9resser